# Suitable Ubuntu distribution

Tags: 13.04, graphics

I need help choosing a suitable distrbution for my PC.

I am using an HP d530 CMT with:

⠀• CPU Type: Intel Pentium 4, 3000 MHz (15 x 200)
⠀• Motherboard Chipset: Intel Springdale-G i865G
⠀• System Memory: 1015 MB  (PC3200 DDR SDRAM)
⠀• Video Adapter: Intel(R) 82865G Graphics Controller (96 MB)
⠀• 3D Accelerator: Intel Extreme Graphics 2
⠀• Audio Adapter: Analog Devices AD1981B(L) @ Intel 82801EB ICH5 - AC'97 Audio Controller
⠀• Network Adapter: Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet

I have tried to install Ubuntu 13.10 and 12.04 LTS.
Everything is OK on Ubuntu 12.04 except, that the video card was not recognized and the media player, YouTube,etc. did not work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Try Lubuntu 13.10 first. I believe it has the lowest graphics requirements of all Ubuntu flavours.

Still, your setup is very weak graphics-wise, so don't expect to be able to use YouTube etc. with it. You might consider buying an old videocard for your computer.